# Cannot evaluate matplotlib in Python code block

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-babel, python

These are my first attempts to plot graph in Python.
Following [this example](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html#org78318b3) , I tried a very simple graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
plt.savefig('python-matplot-fig.png')
return 'python-matplot-fig.png' # return filename to org-mode
```

I got an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in main
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

Whereas I have the python installed and running on my system.

On VsCode, it is calculated

[image]

I use spacemacs python layer

```
  dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     (python
      :variables
      python-backend 'anaconda
      python-format-on-save t
      python-sort-imports-on-save t)
```

Comment: Try without a `:session` header arg. Python processing in Org bbel is subtly different between sessions and non-sessions. Or use `:session` but get rid of the `return` in your code (which is what the linked page shows). Also, this tends to be fragile, so depending on your version of Org mode, you might (or might not) hit other problems. You should post the version as part of your question.

Comment: I'd guess Emacs is using a different Python? Perhaps the system Python which does not have matplotlib installed by default?

Comment: @NickD : org 9.3.6

Answer (score 1):

The python version used by org-babel was 2.7.8

To use the "last" version of Python on my system, I used in my init.el file

```
(setq org-babel-python-command "python3")
```

then all librairies installed by `pip` in my terminal were usable

Comment: @mankoff had it right.